# jQuery debug and selector assistance with checkbox and div

Tags: jquery, debugging, html, checkbox, css-selectors

I have multiple tables on my page that contain a checkbox.  Immediately following the table is a div that by default is hidden.  I want to show/hide the div depending on the checkbox selection.

Since I have about 10 of these structures, I want to figure out a way to create one click selection to handle any one that is clicked.

The HTML:

```
<table>  
<input id='cbChecklist1'>  
</table>

<div id='divChecklist1'>  
Show/Hide  
</div>
```

So I have cbChecklist1-cbChecklist10 and divChecklist1-divChecklist10.  When a checkbox in the tab that has cbChecklistX I want it to show/hide the corresponding divChecklistX.

Thanks!

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@EDIT@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

I've changed the design of my checkboxes and tables and I'm trying to use the slideDown, slideUp methods, but it doesn't seem like I'm properly selecting my proper `<div>` -- at least it is not sliding the `<div>` up and down.

2 Questions:
1. Am I properly modifying the `<div>` selector?
2. How do I debug this to know how the selection is working?

Updated HTML:

```
<table>  
<input id='cbPressueChecklist'>  
</table>

<div id='divPressueChecklist'>  
Show/Hide  
</div>


<table>  
<input id='cbMechanicalChecklist'>  
</table>

<div id='divMechanicalChecklist'>  
Show/Hide  
</div>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$('input[id$=Checklist]').change(function()  
{  
    var divId = '#div' + this.id.substring(2);  
    if (this.checked)  
        $(divId).slideDown(1500);  
    else  
        $(divId).hide(1500);  
});
```

Again, thanks.

Comment: Is it always `table`, `div`, `table`, `div`...or is it one large `table` containing all the check-boxes followed by all the `div`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[id^=cbChecklist]').change(function() {
    var divId = '#divChecklist' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $( divId ).toggle( this.checked );
});
```

This binds [a `.change()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to `<input>` elements where the ID [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with/) `cbChecklist`.

When a change event occurs, it extracts the number from its ID, and concatenates it to `#divChecklist` to create the selector.

Then [`.toggle()` is called](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on the related `<div>`, passing `this.checked` as a switch so that if the box is checked, it will `show` the `<div>`, otherwise it will `hide`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I made an edit based on a new design, with a new problem.  Your help would be great!

Comment: @Mark - Your new code looks correct. To debug, use the developer tools that come with Chrome/Safari, or install Firebug into Firefox. Then do `console.log( divId );`, or to see the selected element, log the jQuery object `console.log( $(divId) );`. Of course you should be able to see the result when your code runs too.